# Casting terms in operations & instance variables

Tags: java

I was going over a few assignments and could not not help but wonder what difference of casting variables in an operation is: i.e.

```
public class Averager{
    private int sum = 0;
    private int count = 0;

    public int getSum(){
        return sum;
    }
    public void add(int val){
        sum += val;
        count++;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public double getAverage(){
        return (double)sum/(double)count;
    }
}
```

Specifically what is the difference between:

```
(double)(sum/count); // casting the result of the operation
// explicitly casting the sum and I assume count is implicitly up casted to double, since one of variables is a double (sum)
(double)sum / count; //alternatively sum / (double)count
(double)sum / (double)count // explicitly casting both variables
```

And my second question is regarding instance variables:

```
public class GasTank{
    private double amount = 0;
    public void addGas(double value){
        this.amount += value;
    }
    public void useGas(double value){
        this.amount -= value;
    }
    public double getGasLevel(){
        return amount;
    }
}
```

I could have written the return statement in getGasLevel() as return this.amount
From what I understand the this keyword refrences the current instance or implementation of an object and its members/properties...My question specifically is what is the best practice, to defin instance variables with the this keyword or without when writing methods. From what I've been told, it is a java convention to write mutator methods in this way (`public void setVar(type var){this.var = var;}` 
should I use the this keyword whenever manipulating instance variables within the class they're defined?

Comment: For question #1 Google "Java Integer arithmetic".

Comment: For question #2 - Inside its own class use `this` only to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (double)(sum/count); // casting the result of the operation

The `int` result of `sum/count` (because both are `int`) widened to a `double`. (3/2) would be 1.

> (double)sum / count; //alternatively sum / (double)count
>
> (double)sum / (double)count // explicitly casting both variables

The `double` result of `sum/count` (because at least one of the terms is a `double`). (3/2) would be `1.5`

As for using `this`, it is necessary when the variable name shadows the field name. It can help to clarify that you intend to modify a field... for example, it can help prevent bugs like

```
private String field;
public void setField(String value) {
    value = field;
}
```

Comment: I see how this makes sense for setters. Would it make sense to use this when defining constructors?: i.e MyClass(int var) { this.var = var; }

Comment: Yes. For the same reason.